# ‘_io.TextIOWrapper’ object is not subscriptable error in python3

Tags: python

I am working on a little program to eat away my day for me! And I am reading a file and storing each line in a variable like this:

```
cline = f[num_lines]
```

I have no idea why that error is popping up for that line here is my full code:

```
import os
number_lines = 1
print('Enter the filepath to the file you want to read.')
fpath = input('Enter: ')
print('okay')
with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cline = f[num_lines]
        originalline = number_lines
        number_lines += 1
        length = len(line)
        if cline[0] == 'e' and cline[1] == 'c' and cline[2] == 'h' and cline[3] == 'o' and cline[4] == '':
          echoing = cline[5:length]
          print(echoing)
        else:
          print('N# Does not recognize that command! In line: ' + str(originalline))
```

Thank you in advance I have no idea why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
cline = f[num_lines]
```

does not work because `f` is a `TextIOWrapper` (or file) object, and it doesn't provide a `__getitem__` method, which is what permits `[index]` operations.  Also, `num_lines` is not defined.  The content of the current line is already held in the variable `line`, so there is not need to define `cline`.

This version of the code works (I amended the final string test to be `line[4] == " "` because `line[4] == ""` can never be true).

```
number_lines = 1
print("Enter the filepath to the file you want to read.")
fpath = input("Enter: ")
print("okay")
with open(fpath, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        originalline = number_lines
        number_lines += 1
        length = len(line)
        if (
            line[0] == "e"
            and line[1] == "c"
            and line[2] == "h"
            and line[3] == "o"
            and line[4] == " "
        ):
            echoing = line[5:length]
            print(echoing)
        else:
            print("N# Does not recognize that command! In line: " + str(originalline))
```

If you want, you can reduce the amount of code by using the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin function to track th line number, and [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to test the beginning of each line.

```
print("Enter the filepath to the file you want to read.")
fpath = input("Enter: ")
print("okay")
with open(fpath, "r") as f:
    for number_lines, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        length = len(line)
        if line.startswith("echo "):
            echoing = line[5:length]
            print(echoing)
        else:
            print("N# Does not recognize that command! In line: " + str(number_lines))
```